# How to disable the movement of the Tkinter Window without removing the title bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter

I have been creating an application for taking the test. So, for that, I have to do two things.
First, disable the drag of the Tkinter window and don't let the user focus on other windows rather than my application window. This means I wanted to make my application such that, No other application can be used while my application is in use.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux? Also why do you want to keep the title bar? The user can always use the minimise button to minimise the window.

Comment: @TheLizzard I am on Windows10 and it's ok if there is any solution by removing the title bar.
My main motto is not to allow the user to use any other application while my application is in use.

Comment: I was thinking of forcing the window to be above all applications and when unfocused it forces focus again. It will be easier to do if it doesn't have the title bar but I will try to also give a solution with the title bar.

Comment: Do some research on the `grab` method.

Comment: @BryanOakley I also tried the grab method but it also didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class FocusedWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        # Force it to be unminimisable
        super().overrideredirect(True)

        # Force it to always be on the top
        super().attributes("-topmost", True)

        # Even if the user unfoceses it, focus it
        super().bind("<FocusOut>", lambda event: self.focus_force())

        # Take over the whole screen
        width = super().winfo_screenwidth()
        height = super().winfo_screenheight()
        super().geometry("%ix%i+0+0" % (width, height))


root = FocusedWindow()
# You can use it as if it is a normal `tk.Tk()`
button = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

That removed the title bar but you can always create your own one by using `tkinter.Label`s and `tkinter.Button`s. I tried making it work with the title bar but I can't refocus the window for some reason.

Comment: Thank You very much
I am really thankful to you
Hope If you could provide me with your GitHub ID as I will add you as a contributor.

Comment: @AakarshKumar I have a few GitHub projects of my own but if you want it, [this](https://github.com/TheLizzard/) is it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by the following, another could be to overwrite the `.geometry()` method of tkinter.

In the following code I simply had get the position by using `winfo_rootx` and `winfo_rooty`. After this you can force the window by calling the geometry method via binding the  event every time the window is configured.

```
import tkinter as tk

def get_pos():
    global x,y
    x = root.winfo_rootx()
    y = root.winfo_rooty()
def fix_pos():
    root.bind('<Configure>', stay_at)
def stay_at(event):
    root.geometry('+%s+%s' % (x,y))

root = tk.Tk()
button1 = tk.Button(root, text='get_pos', command=get_pos)
button2 = tk.Button(root, text='fix_pos', command=fix_pos)

button1.pack()
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am still able to focus other windows. This isn't ideal for a test app :D

Comment: @TheLizzard I'm sure you can tell him.